# my CSS rules loads AFTER my jQuery functions execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm facing a difficulty in how CSS and jQuery communicates, I think (?).

In CSS I often write my rules as direct child, too increase specificity, like

```
div#container > div#contentLeft {
   //Code here
}
```

Then when I try to make my site amazing with jQuery the CSS rules loads after my jQuery code executes. I wish that the CSS loads before so the content is nice and tidy with my animations.

This could be fixed by writing less specified code, example: #contentLeft {}. Then when I try my script the CSS is loaded and then my script runs as intended.

I want to code with high specificity... But can I if I want my jQuery running as smooth as I want?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/459epctg/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contentMenu').show('slide', {
    direction: 'up'
  }, 1000);
  showContent();
});

function showContent() {
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    $('#contentMenu').delay(1000).show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentLocations').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentSpecials').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentGifts').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#locations').click(function() {
    $('#contentMenu').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentLocations').delay(1000).show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentSpecials').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentGifts').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#specials').click(function() {
    $('#contentMenu').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentLocations').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentSpecials').delay(1000).show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentGifts').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#gifts').click(function() {
    $('#contentMenu').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentLocations').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentSpecials').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#contentGifts').delay(1000).show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #CDBFAC;
}
div#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
}
div#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CDBFAC;
}
div#navbar > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
div#navbar > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #148FC7;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
div#content > div#contentMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #004660;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
div#content > div#contentLocations {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #004660;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
div#content > div#contentSpecials {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #004660;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
div#content > div#contentSpecials > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
div#content > div#contentGifts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #004660;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
div#content > div#contentGifts button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div#content > div#contentMenu > h1,
div#content > div#contentMenu > h4,
div#content > div#contentMenu > ul,
div#content > div#contentMenu > ul > li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div#content > div#contentLocations > h1,
div#content > div#contentLocations > p,
div#content > div#contentLocations > h4,
div#content > div#contentLocations > ul,
div#content > div#contentLocations > ul > li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div#content > div#contentSpecials > h1,
div#content > div#contentSpecials > p div#content > div#contentSpecials > h4,
div#content > div#contentSpecials > ul,
div#content > div#contentSpecials > ul > li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div#content > div#contentGifts > h1,
div#content > div#contentGifts > p,
div#content > div#contentGifts > h4,
div#content > div#contentGifts > ul,
div#content > div#contentGifts > ul > li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu">Menu</li>
      <li id="locations">Locations</li>
      <li id="specials">Specials</li>
      <li id="gifts">Gifts</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="contentMenu">
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <h4>This is our menu</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Pork filé</li>
        <li>Mashed potatoes</li>
        <li>Very Bloody Steak</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contentLocations">
      <h1>Locations</h1>
      <p>We got 100 restaurants and this is one of 'em</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentSpecials">
      <h1>Specials</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>BBQ on a plastic plate</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contentGifts">
      <h1>Gifts</h1>
      <p>All of our guests recieve an awesome gift on arrival</p>
      <button>Click to reveal the awesome gift</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively  why don't you use `$(window).load(function() {` in place of document.ready?

Comment: You also have 2 different versions of jquery in your html. script tags should'nt be outside the html tag

Comment: @atmd the first tag for jquery was the one included with the snnipet...and the last scripts are the ones of the OP

Comment: I tried using $(window).load(function() {} instead of document.ready but it didn't solve anything at all. My jQuery function still executes while my CSS loads after the jQuery function is done which results in a really bad looking design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you call your functions with valid parameters. Your rules were loaded without a problem, but you have an error in your code. You have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentMenu').show('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 1000);
    showContent();
});
```

However, there is no such call possibility for `.show()`, read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/). After reading the other parts of your code, I suppose you wanted this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentMenu').delay(1000).show('slide', {direction: 'up'});
    showContent();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/459epctg/1/). Whenever you encounter a problem, do not miss the possibility to check your console and debug.

Comment: The problem here is not the duration of my events. The problem is that my CSS is not loaded before the event occurs. This results that when I click on a list object my function executes and makes a div slide down from the top and when the div is finished sliding the CSS loads and then I click the list object again the CSS goes away and the function slides the div back up. This causes a poor design with flickering divs... 

I want my CSS to be loaded before the div slides down and remain there when the div slides back up...

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle? It was not the duration. It was a syntax error in your code.

Comment: I can't find the syntax error. Where is it displayed?

Comment: Have you read my answer? Your call for $('#contentMenu').show('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 1000); is incorrect, there is no show functiion with this type of parameter list. This is correct: $('#contentMenu').delay(1000).show('slide', {direction: 'up'}); If you had taken the time to attentively read my answer, this problem has been solved a long time ago.

Comment: I've read your answer. I've changed my code to what you suggested. It's not working. The CSS is not loading properly before my DIV slides down. It loads after the DIV has slided down. That's why I have not marked an answer as the correct one.
Still bashing my head around this.

Comment: My problem is solved by typing less specified CSS code however.
If I change my rules, for example: 
    div#content > div#contentMenu { }
too 

div#contentMenu {}
it works perfectly fine. My CSS is loaded when my jQuery function slides my DIV down to the correct place.

How come? Why does changing too less specificity solve this?